# wordpress Simple Job board plugin hide cv attachment form

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want applicants do not upload their resumes. We would like to disable the upload of the resumes and just have them send them to an email address. But we can’t find anywhere to remove the resume upload field from the form. How can we remove the ability to attach a resume?

I have tried to hide the form through CSS but it is not the solution , 
I know there is a addon for it but I couldn't by it.

Comment: I don't understand you well. Do you want to remove file field from the form? If it's your own form or theme you can remove it from file or it's from plugins you should mention plugins name here or you can see docs or settings of the plugins.

Comment: Yes it is a plugin I have mentioned. But I found one way of removing the field from
which I did by moving the plugin template to my theme directory e.g  "wp-content/plugins/simple-job-board/templates/single-jobpost" to "wp-content/themes/mytheme/simple-job-board" and empty the file "job-application.php" by which the form is no more showing with job details. Do you know any other solution.